# Can a $30 wireless router really transfer with 150Mbps?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, speed, wireless-router

I have just bought a $30 wireless router which claims a transfer rate of 150Mbps.

Can that really be true? Or is this with an assumed compression or some other marketing fine print?

Comment: Well did you test it and see if it worked at 150mbps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason it can't use the 150Mbps protocol in 802.11n. Just keep in mind that like all other current wireless technologies this speed is unswitched half-duplex. It's nowhere near as good as the same 150Mbps would be in a wired network.  Also, like other wireless technologies it's susceptible to interference and airspace conditions. The 150Mbps is a theoretical max that is seldom reached (again, unlike wired networks, where published speed is often is the actual speed).

Comment: Very interesting! I had no idea it was half-duplex. You mentioned the  802.11n protocol. Should I use that? Default was set to `11bgn mixed`. I can choose between: `11b only` `11g only` `11n only` `11gb mixed` `11bng mixed`.

Comment: bgn mixed is okay, as long as both your router and the wireless card in your computer support n.

Comment: It is a Macbook I have. Does that support `n`?

Comment: it depends on the macbook. but know that mac's can be finicky when talking to some of the cheaper non-apple access points/routers.